# how to pass id from Resources controller to view laravel 8

Tags: laravel, eloquent, controller, laravel-8

hello please i want to pass id to my view
if i try this i get the items but i can't hard code dynamic items,

```
public function getDescription(Marketplace $id)
{
    $product = Marketplace::find(17);
    return view('market.description', compact('product'));
}
```

but this return this error Property [product_img] does not exist on this collection instance. (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\sellout\resources\views\market\description.blade.php)

```
public function getDescription(Marketplace $id)
{
    $product = Marketplace::find($id);
    return view('market.description', compact('product'));
}
```

Routes:

```
Route::get('market/product-description', [MarketsPlaceController::class, 'getDescription']);
Route::post('market/product-description', [MarketsPlaceController::class, 'getDescription'])->name('productDesc');
Route::resource('market', MarketsPlaceController::class);
```

Comment: this my route ..... Route::get('market/product-description', [MarketsPlaceController::class, ('getDescription')]);
        Route::post('market/product-description', [MarketsPlaceController::class, ('getDescription')])->name('productDesc');
        Route::resource('market', MarketsPlaceController::class);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have a route paremeter defined for the route that goes to that action so `$id` is a new non existing instance of the `Marketplace` model. It is not an identifier as there is no route parameter.

When you are passing that non existing instance (new instance) of `Marketplace` to `Marketplace::find($id)` that instance is `Arrayable` so `toArray` is called on it to return the attributes/relationships. Since it is new it doesn't have any attributes and ends up being an empty array. This will cause an empty Collection to be returned.

At the moment you have no ability to actual pass the record you want to your view since you don't have a route parameter for it defined. If you defined a route parameter you could then use something like Route Model Binding to find the record automatically for you:

```
Route::get('market/{marketplace}/product-description', [MarketPlacesController::class, 'getDescription']);

public function getDescription(Marketplace $marketplace)
{
    return view('market.description', ['product' => $marketplace]);
}
```

*Assuming `Marketplace` is an Eloquent Model*

Comment: Thanks @lagbox, have tried your suggestion it still return empty data the page opens, i have the id on the address bar but not returning the product's details. thanks

Comment: @Barnabaskoloz show the route and URL you are using

Comment: am so gratefull man i just checked the route and noticed i didnt pass the {marketplace} parameter in my post Route. i did and its working perfectly man i appreciate your time and effort